# Get data through multiple services to component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I want to use two services, one use to make rest call and to other one to manage complexe code execution.
In my case i have :

```
Car.service.ts
CarRest.service.ts
Car.component.ts
form.component.ts
```

My form.component.ts is calling Car.service.ts which is calling CarRest.service.ts to send and get data from the backend and it should gives from Car.service.ts this data (eventuals errors, success etc..) to my Car.component.ts.

I don't know how to explain it but i would like to make two subscription one from car.component to car.service and the other one from car.servcie to carRest.service.ts and it should get all errors or sucess in my car.component in order to print it. How can i do it ? Is it good to make two subcription ?

Thanks a lot for helping !!

Answer (score 0):

please expalin more about your problem.do you want to call CarService and if that was success call CarRestService.
if it is true you must use  some operators of rxjs.
maybe your code will be like this:

```
callApi() {
  return of(true).pipe(
   concatMap(c=>this.carService.someMethod()), 
   concatMap(c=>this.carRestService.someMethod(c)),
   catchError(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return throwError(err);
   })
  );
```

}

someMethod return an observable.